How to convert String to JsonNode
I am trying to convert this attribute:
private String templateData;

stored in database to this:
private JsonNode templateData;

, but my String looks like this: firstName, lastName and I need it to look like:
"firstName": "Josh",
"lastName": "Doe"

when Josh and Doe are passed as parameters from user something like this:
private String firstName
private String lastName

This is snippet from my DB: DB
and this is snipper from my Swagger UI: swagger UI

Is the value in the DB already in JSON format or just simple string concatenation?

it is stored as String

What exactly is the string you start with? I.e. can you give a real example of my String looks like this: firstName, lastName (do you mean you store "Josh, Doe" in the db?)

I uploaded photos into the post

so you have a "template" of "firstName, lastName" and need to dynamically run code like jsonMapper.createObjectNode().put("firstName", "Josh").put("lastName", "Doe") from it. E.g. you could split & trim the template to extract the fields you need, then lookup where to get those values and then call .put(key, value) for each field

you can use the same approach to convert a String to a JsonNode using the Jackson library
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class JsonConverter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public JsonNode convertStringToJsonNode(String firstName, String lastName) {
        try {
            // Create a map with the key-value pairs
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("firstName", firstName);
            data.put("lastName", lastName);

            // Convert the map to a JsonNode
            return objectMapper.valueToTree(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

we have a JsonConverter class that is marked as a @Component, so it can be auto-wired into other classes in your Spring Boot application.
The ObjectMapper instance is injected into the JsonConverter class via constructor injection. Spring Boot automatically configures and provides an instance of ObjectMapper for you.
You can then use the JsonConverter class in your other components or services
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {
    private final JsonConverter jsonConverter;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(JsonConverter jsonConverter) {
        this.jsonConverter = jsonConverter;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        String firstName = "Josh";
        String lastName = "Doe";

        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonConverter.convertStringToJsonNode(firstName, lastName);
        // Do something with the jsonNode
        System.out.println(jsonNode.toString());
    }
}

